# How can I monitor byte usage for Studio voices on the Google Cloud Text-to-Speech API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-text-to-speech

For a while now I have been using Google Cloud text-to-speech API with @Voice Aloud reader. Previously, I have been able to monitor my usage because pricing was based on characters, with WaveNet voices allowing for up to a million characters and $0.000016 USD per character after that.

I am very impressed with the new Studio voices and would like to try out using them, but the pricing for them is much higher and is based on bytes per month, with a cost of $0.00016 USD per byte or $160.00 per million bytes.

So, I need to figure out how to monitor and preferably cap my byte usage for the API I created, but I have no idea how to do this.

I'm tech savvy enough to be able to set up the API with instructions, but I have no idea how to strike out on my own and set up a quota without guidance, and I have not been able to find any.

I expected the Google Cloud API to have an obvious place where monthly byte usage was shown and a way to cap it, but while I have found the quotas area of Google Cloud, I have to idea how to actually make it do what I want.

I went into the quotas section and found data on "Requests" and latency, but nothing on actual byte consumption that I can discern. I tried to create a quota, but cannot figure out how to make one that targets byte usage by month.

Comment: You can view current usage and quota using the Google Cloud console's [API dashboard](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard?_ga=2.221771480.1550360314.1675655584-1825960524.1667376602&_gac=1.21204297.1675944150.CjwKCAiA0JKfBhBIEiwAPhZXD0ek2vdX-YOZcp8WwI3D59sMRPv2Z_QSPKPiOl7s0jHqqrz7XWfX8hoC1CIQAvD_BwE). Can you try creating [quota alert](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota?&_ga=2.60966892.-1143421613.1678189128&_gac=1.220740202.1678807094.Cj0KCQjwtsCgBhDEARIsAE7RYh0R35CChlUa9xX_4D_lWXlz4R_lGn7PHacuA0SlXYvUbvufQ7xrxkQaAvIjEALw_wcB#viewing_your_quota_console) as per your requirement?